# Double integral on the circle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I am stuck with the following xy-plane integral:

$$
\int_{x^2+y^2\leq3^2}\sqrt{25-y^2}dxdy.
$$

Putting in in polar coordinates, one finds

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Bigg(\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{25-\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)}\rho\,d\rho\Bigg)\,d\theta&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Bigg(\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{25-\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)}\rho\,d\rho\Bigg)\,d\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2\sin^2(\theta)}\Bigg(\int_{0}^{3}-2\rho\sin^2(\theta)\sqrt{25-\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)}\,d\rho\Bigg)\,d\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2\sin^2(\theta)}\Bigg[\frac{2}{3}\big(25-\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}|^{3}_{0}\Bigg]\,d\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2\sin^2(\theta)}\Bigg[\frac{2}{3}\big(25-9\sin^2(\theta)\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{2}{3}\big(25\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}\Bigg]\,d\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Bigg(-\frac{\big(25-9\sin^2(\theta)\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3\sin^2(\theta)}+\frac{125}{3\sin^2(\theta)}\Bigg)\,d\theta
\end{align}
$$
and there I cannot come up with anything encouraging (by the way, I don't know if it is so legit to multiply and divide by something like $\sin(\theta)$ since $\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}$ has a singularity in $[0,2\pi]$).

Comment: Do you know how to perform a trigonometric substitution? This method might be easier in this case...

Comment: @JG123: I doubt it. I see no reason that this integration should be elementary. It will undoubtedly involve elliptic integrals.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I believe you are correct.

Comment: Trig substitution will produce $\int\sqrt{25-y^2}\,dy = \frac{1}{2}y\sqrt{25-y^2} + \frac{25}{2}\arcsin\frac{y}{5} + C$

Comment: @Axion004: Yes, of course. Now go on.

Comment: Then, $\int\int\sqrt{25-y^2}\,dydx = \frac{xy}{2}\sqrt{25-y^2} + \frac{25x}{2}\arcsin\frac{y}{5} + C_1(x)+C_2$.

But, I'm not sure how one would simplify the $x^2+y^2 \leq 3$

Answer (score 1):

You want to evaluate $$\iint_{x^2+y^2\le 3}{\sqrt{25-y^2}\mathrm d x \mathrm d y},$$ so that we have $$\int_{-\sqrt 3}^{\sqrt 3}\int_{-\sqrt {3-y^2}}^{\sqrt {3-y^2}}{\sqrt{25-y^2}\mathrm d x \mathrm d y}=4\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt {3-y^2}}{\sqrt{25-y^2}\mathrm d x \mathrm d y}=4\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt{25-y^2}\sqrt {3-y^2}\mathrm d y},$$ which is not elementary.

Answer (score 0):

Your result in the last equation is correct. Although there is singularity, the integral is converging.

It may be a bit encouraging that your result could be translated into a cleaner form below, with the variable change $t=\cot^2\theta$,

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Bigg[\frac{125}{3\sin^2\theta}-\frac{\big(25-9\sin^2\theta\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3\sin^2\theta}\Bigg]\,d\theta
=\frac{500}{3}\int_0^{\infty} \left[ 1-\left( \frac{a^2+t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]dt
$$

where $a=4/5$. It converges as $t\rightarrow \infty$. But, unfortunately, it could not be integrated with elementary calculus, which has to resort to special elliptic functions.